# Two sliders controlling one line plot

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to have two sliders controlling a single line plot in preferably plotly. for example y = A*sin(Freq*x) where A is the amplitude, Freq is the frequency and x is the time and where A and Freq are controlled by two sliders.

The code I have tried so far can be found below.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
from plotly.offline import plot

# Define the sine wave function

def sine_wave(amplitude, frequency, x):
return amplitude \* np.sin(frequency \* x)

# Initial values for amplitude and frequency

initial_amplitude = 1
initial_frequency = 1

# X values

x = np.linspace(0, 2 \* np.pi, 400)

# Initialize figure

fig = go.Figure(data=\[go.Scatter(x=x, y=sine_wave(initial_amplitude, initial_frequency, x),           mode='lines')\])

# Create amplitude slider

amp_slider = {
              'pad': {'t': 50},
              'len': 0.4,
              'x': 0.1,
              'y': 0,
              'steps': \[{'method': 'restyle',
              'label': str(a),
              'args': \[{'y': \[sine_wave(a, initial_frequency, x)\]},
              \[0\]\]} for a in np.linspace(0.1, 10, 100)\]
             }
```

## Create frequency slider

```
freq_slider = {
'pad': {'t': 50},
'len': 0.4,
'x': 0.6,
'y': 0,
'steps': \[{'method': 'restyle',
'label': str(f),
'args': \[{'y': \[sine_wave(initial_amplitude, f, x)\]},
\[0\]\]} for f in np.linspace(0.1, 10, 100)\]
}

fig.update_layout(sliders=\[amp_slider, freq_slider\])

# Function to update the plot

def update_plot(attrname, old, new):
amp = amp_slider.value
freq = freq_slider.value
new_y = sine_wave(amp, freq, x)
source.data = {'x': x, 'y': new_y}

# Show the figure

fig.show()\`
```

It only works as far as it will either control frequency or amplitude, never two at the same time. if I change frequency amplitude will reset to the initial value.

Comment: i believe such a solution is possible using `plotly-dash` because you can save states. if you're interested, i could add such a solution

Comment: with plotly alone [this use case is not supported](https://community.plotly.com/t/two-slider-controls-for-single-plot-with-two-parameters/13900), so I would go @DerekO's way